# SimpleIntegerProperty from TextField

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding

I need to compute the sum of several text input fields. Rather straight forward but I've been struggeling with the correct conversion and casting for a few hours now.

I have a number of textfields and need to bind their text properties to SimpleIntegerProperties, or at least I think, to finally compute their sum.
This is what I got stuck with last:

```
IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
NumberStringConverter converter = new NumberStringConverter();
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.textProperty().addListener(
    new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(
        ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
        String oldValue, String newValue) {
        if (!newValue.matches("[1-9]\\d{0,3}")) {
            textField.setText(oldValue);
            }}});
value.bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), converter);
```

I saw solutions using the converter as argument for the bidirectional bind but it gives me an error saying it is one argument too many.
I also tried `value.bindBidirectional(converter.fromString(textField.textProperty().get()));` which doesn't work either. This time saying that Number can't be converted to Property Number.

This is a homework question, but neither studying the provided material nor the documentation got me further in the past 3 hours, hence the post.
We are required to use textFields, bidirectional binding, simpleIntegerProperties and the NumberStringConverter.

Comment: What exactly did you try when you got "one argument too many"? Did you use [`Bindings.bindBidirectional(Property,Property,StringConverter)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindBidirectional(javafx.beans.property.Property,javafx.beans.property.Property,javafx.util.StringConverter))? And why are you required to use bidirectional bindings? Are these `IntegerProperty`s supposed to be part of some model?

Comment: It says that `IntegerProperty cannot apply method bindBidirectional. Required: <Property>Number. Found: StringProperty, NumberStringConverter`. I tried that too, but it didn't work. But I don't remember why. I have been wondering about that too. We have not yet learned about models I believe

Comment: Note that the bindBidirectional method you should use is not a method of `value`, but rather a static method of JavaFX’s Bindings class.

Comment: out in the real, you would use a TextFormatter which uses a NumberFormat to decide whether the input of the textField is valid and then bidi-bind its value to any outside integer as needed. Just a nitpick to remember for later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently this `value.bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), converter);` doesn't work. This, however, does: `textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(value, converter);`

Comment: glad you found the solution - api doc is very helpful, I presume :) Actually, I wasn't aware of StringProperty's bidi-binding method that takes a converter, so thanks for providing my learn item of the day :)